# Elección de moderador de comunidad 2019 (2 posiciones disponibles)

Tags: discusión, moderadores, elecciones

¡La elección de moderador de comunidad de 2019 está en marcha!

Las elecciones de moderador de comunidad tienen tres etapas:

1. Etapa de postulación
2. Etapa primaria
3. Etapa de elección

La mayoría de las elecciones llevan entre dos y tres semanas, pero esto depende de la cantidad de candidatos que haya.

Consulta la página de elección oficial en

https://es.stackoverflow.com/election

para obtener más información, ¡y participar!

Si deseas formular preguntas generales sobre el proceso de elección o preguntas para los candidatos a moderador, puedes hacerlo aquí en Meta; solo asegúrate de que tus preguntas tengan la etiqueta [elecciones](/questions/tagged/elecciones).